# XCode 6/Swift button label

Tags: swift, properties, xcode6, ibaction

The code below shows what I have found by searching for help but have been unable to find something that shows me what I am really looking for. I'm trying to get the value of the button's label that shows in the Identity Inspector under the Document section and on the scene tree.

[image]

```
@IBAction func pressedKeypad(sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
    print(sender.titleLabel)
    print(" keytitle is \(keytitle).")        
}
```

The above code yields these three outputs, but they are not what I want.

```
Optional("3")

Optional(<UIButtonLabel: 0x7b7b10a0; frame = (27 14; 18.5 36); text = '3'; alpha = 0.2; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7b7b11c0>>)

keytitle is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The label shown under the Document section (`btn02` in your screen shot) is purely internal to Interface Builder and cannot be retrieved via code. When the app runs and the nib loads, the label doesn't even *exist*. It is purely for your use in identifying a view within Interface Builder.

If the problem is that you are looking for a way to *identify* which button sent you the `pressedKeypad` message, you can use something like its `tag` (which you can also assign in Interface Builder: you assign it as a string but it arrives to you as a number).